# CORS problem with XMLHttpRequest from localhost to REST service with FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cors, xmlhttprequest

Now when I am opening a development page on my localhost using IIS server and trying to make a `XMLHttpRequest` to a REST service on another server usin FireFox, I got this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://carto48dev.education.gouv.qc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/DEV/AUTH_SERVICES/GPServer/Login/execute.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match
>   ‘https://localhost:8080’).

This problem seems to be new in FireFox (version 62.0.2) as it was working before and I dont have this problem using Chrome or IE.

**I would like to understand why it was working before and not now, and why it's still working in Chrome but not in FireFox**

**Is it most likely that something was changed on the REST service or something in FireFox security?**

Here is the response headers from the REST service:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Cache-Control: max-age=0,must-revalidate, max-age=60
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 12:30:29 GMT
Expires: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 12:41:30 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Set-Cookie: UqZBpD3n3iPIDwJU9Am+pGqSSQ@@=v…Sep-2028 12:30:28 GMT; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Accept-encoding
```

Here is how I make the `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function makeRequest(url, postData, options)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        url = options.method == "GET" ? url + "?" + _encodePostData(postData) : url;
        xhr.open(options.method, url, options.async);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                //service internal error
                if (response.results[1].value) {
                    reject(response.results[1].value);
                } else {
                    resolve(response.results[0].value);
                }
            }
        };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, further investigations proved that the problem was laying in a FireFox addon, ie: **DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add CORS headers in the server side

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
```

Comment: Ok thank you, do you have an idea why it was working before and not now, and why it's still working in Chrome but not in FireFox?

Comment: browsers handle AJAX/ XMLHttpRequests differently, we'll need to provide appropriate headers in our server side